# Debugging processes spawned by another

Tags: c#, debugging, process, visual-studio-debugging, multiprocess

I have written a program that spawns a handful of processes.

By default, Visual Studio does not debug the new processes -- only the original process that created the new ones.

Is there a way to automatically, in code, connect Visual Studio up to the processes when they are created?

Comment: Since you're asking for VS options I am just going to mention this as a comment. WinDbg + SOS allows you to automatically attach to child processes.

Comment: Is the second process a project in the same solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll have to write a VS Add-in or a VS Package, because you'll want to sit in the background and wait for child processes to load.

Here's a general recipe of what you'll want to do:

1. Get the ID of the debuggee process (ie, `uint processID = DTE.Debugger.CurrentProcess.ProcessID`)
2. Add reference to System.Management and use a `ManagementEventWatcher` to listen for new processes creation as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor). Your query should be `"SELECT ProcessID FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ParentProcessID = " + processID`
3. When a new child process loads, find it by its processID in `DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses`, then call `.Attach()` on it.

Answer (score 3):

From: [debugging a process spawned with CreateProcess in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574853/debugging-a-process-spawned-with-createprocess-in-visual-studio)

> You can temporarily put in a call to DebugBreak() somewhere in the
>   startup code of your child process. This will cause Windows to prompt
>   you if you want to debug that process.

**EDIT:**
Since both projects are in the same solution, configure VS for multi-project debugging:
(VS2010)
Context-click the solution node in `Solution Explorer`
Choose `Set Startup Projects...`
On the dialog select `Multiple startup projects` radio button
In the Project grid change the `Action` for all the projects you wish to debug to `Start`

Comment: I don't want to do something temporary; in my parent process, I want to check if it is being debugged and automatically attach the debugger.

Comment: Well this answer solves it from the child side.. but `Temporary` is all about whether you remove the code or not.. completely up to you.

Comment: Even with the popup, it'll be a second debugger, not the primary debugger instance.

Comment: As per the original question, the processes are spawned by my main application. I can't start it up in VS.

Comment: As a side note, you can achieve the same effect as temporarily adding DebugBreak(), but without having to change code and recompile, by using GFlags http://bugslasher.net/2011/03/26/how-to-debug-a-process-as-soon-as-it-starts-with-windbg-or-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 2):

This still provides a prompt, but does attach the debugger:

```
if (!Debugger.IsAttached && DebuggerFlagSet()) Debugger.Launch();
```

and then in the parent process

```
if(Debugger.IsAttached)
    SetDebuggerFlag()
```

You'll need a mechanism for the debugger flag such as a file on disk/reg key/mutex etc.

The debugger being launched won't be the same as the initial instance.